# Java. Cannot import SHA256withRSA signature from import java.security.Signature

Tags: java, encryption, java-security, rsa-sha256

I'm trying to initialize SHA256withRSA Signature object:

```
Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
```

But compiler generates `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, but when I run this code:

```
import java.security.Signature;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
        for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices())
            if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
                algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());
    for (String algorithm : algorithms)
        System.out.println(algorithm);
}
```

It creates output:

```
...
SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format
SHA256withRSA
SHA384withECDSA
...
```

What i'm doing wrong or what libraries should I include into project?

Comment: Can you include the code which is not working?

Comment: Thanks for response! Question updated.

Comment: I tried this and the code works. Which version of Java are you using? NOTE: The OpenJDK doesn't have the same cryptograph options as the Oracle JDK.

Comment: That exception is from JVM at runtime, not the compiler. But yes if an algorithm is in the services list you should be able to instantiate it. Your posted code has wrong quotemarks and shouldn't compile at all; make sure your real code doesn't, and if it has been exposed to Windows (which likes to screw up quotemarks like that) also check it doesn't have any invisible characters like a BOM or bidi mark or something.